# Doubt in finding $\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{x^2-1}{x^2-2|x-1|-1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I actually have a doubt in finding $\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{x^2-1}{x^2-2|x-1|-1}$. When   I directly simplify this expression I get $\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{x+1}{(x+1)+2}$ which gives 1/2, the required answer. However when I put x = 1-h where h tends to zero, I get $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h-2}{h}$ which doesn't really reach the answer. Why does the second method not give the answer 1/2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, with $h>0$, 
\begin{align}
\frac{(1-h)^2-1}{(1-h)^2-2|h|-1}
=\frac{-2h+h^2}{-2h+h^2-2h}=\frac{h-2}{h-4}\xrightarrow[h\to 0+]{}\frac{-2}{-4}=\frac12.
\end{align}